# Ubuntu 18.04 UI bug?

Tags: 18.04, bug-reporting, interface

```
lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I am not sure if this is an Ubuntu 18.04 bug because it also happens on my Intellij IDEA when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for code auto complete.

[image: Image with bug]

If you look at the image, the bookmark overlay description is now jumbled up with weird tab-like looking characters. These weren't there before for sure and an Ubuntu software update must have caused this.

How do I fix this?

EDIT 1: This happens in Firefox too.

Comment: Maybe the problem is caused by a mismatch between the graphics driver and the graphics chip/card? Please tell us the brand name and model of the computer and particularly the brand name and model of the graphics chip/card.